# AppleScript - Finder set label with absolute path

Tags: macos, label, applescript

I have this working AppleScript that sets a label.  But it asks me to select the file.

Question: how do you specify a path to the file that you want to change the label index to, so you aren't prompted

```
set myPath to (choose folder with prompt "choose")

tell application "Finder"
    set label index of myPath to 2
end tell
```

Comment: Try `set myPath to POSIX file "/Users/YOU/Desktop/SOMEFILE" as alias` in place of current first line.

Comment: Run the `choose folder` command on its own and it should return something that looks like `alias "Drive:folder:"`. You can set your variable using that syntax, e.g. `set myPath to alias "Drive:folder:"`. You can read up on specifying files and folders [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
set myPath to "/Users/John/Desktop/Somefile" as POSIX file as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set label index of myPath to 2
end tell
```